# Symfony profiler toolbar does not show DB Queries

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

In a brand new installation of MAC OS X Lion, latest MAMP and Symfony 2.1.3-DEV version, it seems that the Profiler toolbar does not show the amount of DB Queries in the debug toolbar. I  execute a query with 1 inner join and 2 left joins and see a full dump with \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity);

Does anyone have a clue what may be happening ? This is so strange I do not know where to start searching !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So foolish, the debug was disabled inside app_dev.php

Comment: I know that feeling bro